# Prepopulate and submit hidden form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and here's the handler for the submit button:

```
$( '#submit_btn' ).click( function( data ){ 
    theForm = document.getElementById( 'realForm' );
    theForm.meetingName.value = document.getElementById( 'meeting_name' ).value;
    theForm.meetingId.value = '';
    theForm.description.value = document.getElementById( 'mtg_description' ).value;
    theForm.startTime.value = startDate + ' ' + startTime;
    theForm.endTime.value = endDate + ' ' + endTime;
    theForm.loginName.value = participants;
    theForm.role.value = roles;
    theForm.docRights.value = docRights;
    theForm.submit();
});
```

This handler basically pre-processes some data and sends to a hidden form, this:

```
<form id="realForm" style="visibility:hidden" action="/app/meeting/create" method="post">
    <input name="loginName" type="text">
    <input name="meetingName" type="text">
    <input name="meetingId" type="text">
    <input name="startTime" type="text">
    <input name="endTime" type="text">
    <input name="description" type="text">
    <input name="roles" type="text">
    <input name="docRights" type="text">
</form>
```

Problem is that the request isn't hitting the endpoint defined in the hidden form. What am I doing wrong here?

I've changed to make the input types hidden instead of the form. The submit handler certainly executes and, using FireBug, I don't see the request going out under the NET tab.

I'm using this dummy data to try and trigger the request but it's still not working:

```
theForm.meetingName.value       = "MY MTG";
                        theForm.meetingId.value         = '';
                        theForm.description.value       = "DESC";
                        theForm.startTime.value         = "2013-05-25 00:00:00";
                        theForm.endTime.value           = "2013-05-25 02:00:00";
                        theForm.loginName.value         = "foo@frr.com";
                        theForm.role.value              = "M,M";
                        theForm.docRights.value         = "CRUT,CRUT";
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the submit happens? Or is that the issue? Use Firebug and watch the NET tab (or similar tool).

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have a couple of suggestions.  Have you tried it without the `visibility:hidden` to see if it works?  Also, maybe try 'display:none' instead of 'visibility:hidden'.

Comment: Why not provide a form with Hidden fields instead of the entirely hidden form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that my first form had a button with type = "submit"...so that was submitting the form even though I didn't want it to.

I had to change the type to "button" in order to prevent that from happening.

Thanks for all the prompt responses.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try this out:

```
document.forms.realForm.submit()
```

Answer (score 2):

2 tips:

1. use this for fetching variable from input.

   ```
   $("#NAME_OF_YOUR_INPUT_ID").val();
   ```
2. use hidden input instead and identify each one with ID.

   ```
   <input id="docRights" type="hidden">
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` name is `roles` not `role`.

Change your line of JS to:

```
theForm.roles.value = roles;
```

See JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jav6s/